# How to add image without using query in SQLite (SQLiteAdmin tool) table?

Tags: image, sqlite, blob

How to add image (as BLOB Type) without using query in SQLite (SQLiteAdmin tool) table?

Comment: Is it too late to Base64 encode the image data and just store it as text instead of a BLOB?  Or perhaps even better, store the image in the filesystem and just put the path to it in the database.

Comment: @aroth: I need to add it as a BLOB only..Is there any other way?